# === vs == not working in my php string comparison on web service response

Tags: php, web-services, curl

```
<?php
require_once("curl_client.php");
$data = 
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ns2='http://services.mamca.be.vub/'>
        <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>`
                <ns2:isLoginAccess>
        <userID>78838</userID>
        <password>esther</password>
            </ns2:isLoginAccess>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
$url = "http://mamca.com/MamcaWS?";
$response = curl_soappost_call($url, $data);
echo ($response);
echo '<br>';
if ($response === 'true') {
    echo 'yes';
} 
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

I've posted a snippet of my main code. however, using `==` yields true, making any argument input true. `===` doesn't work for me; all my input yields false against the response string. For example, the response to that code is 'true' but if i run `var_dump`, i can see the soap xml message in full.

My question is that, can the response of a soap message be compared as a string, int, boolean etc?

Here is a sample response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <ns2:isLoginAccessResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.mamca.be.vub/">
     <return>true</return>
  </ns2:isLoginAccessResponse>
 </S:Body>
```

Comment: can you post your response logins also?

Comment: ok i will now. thank you

Comment: You have to first parse that soap response, then extract the required field. its not a simple `true` string

Comment: try if ($response == 'true') { ===(will compare type and value both) may be some missing to match type or value

Comment: ($response == 'true') say true to every thing even when it wrong

Comment: I found the solution, i add to convert the response to a XML file and load the result from the "return" tag.  $response2= curl_soappost_call($url,$data);
        $doc->loadXML($response2);
 $results = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "return" );
 $mainresult = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;